# Typescript: "new this" in extended method returns the base

Tags: typescript, class, extends

So I'm trying to build this models system and I want the load method to return the 'User' type instead of 'Model'.

In Javascript, I belive it works, but in Typescript, the type always refers to the model.

Is it possible to make it return the User type.

```
class Model {
    constructor() { }
    static load() {
        return new this();
    }
}

class User extends Model { }

let user = User.load(); 
// let user: Model <-- I wanted it to be of type User
```

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you return `new User()` from `Model` ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in TypeScript currently.

Comment: I've replaced the image with text, as per [the guidelines on images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).  Hope that's okay with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct support for [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) for the static side of classes.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) for the relevant feature request.  Luckily you can emulate the behavior you want by using a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) instead and making the `load()` method [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the polymorphic instance type. Like this:

```
class Model {
    constructor() { }
    static load<T extends Model>(this: new () => T) {
        return new this();
    }
}
```

Essentially the `load()` method can only be called on an object whose `this` context is a no-arg constructor.  The instance type of `this` is the  generic type parameter `T`, and so `return new this()` produces the return type of `T`.  Therefore, `XXX.load()` should return the same type as the instance type of `XXX`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
class User extends Model {
    name = "abc"
}
let user = User.load(); // let user: User
console.log(user.name.toUpperCase()) // "ABC"
```

Looks good, now `user` is of type `User` as desired.

---

Also, note that you have to call it on a class whose constructor needs no arguments.  If you create a class that doesn't work this way:

```
class Confuser extends Model {
    constructor(public name: string) {
        super();
    }
}
```

Then it will inherit the static `load()` method but the compiler won't let you call it:

```
let confuser = Confuser.load(); // error!
// Type 'new (name: string) => Confuser' is not assignable to type 'new () => Confuser'
```

which is a *good thing*, because `new this()` will fail to supply the required constructor argument, and thus could lead to runtime problems:

```
console.log(confuser.name.toUpperCase()) // compiler is happy, but:
//  RUNTIME ERROR, confuser.name is undefined
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgOYEtLgK4CMB0BjAewFthjV8AnQuQgM0mABUBPGAUwGUrUZHU4cTOzjAArAA4AbAGYAUHPwAbAIaDQAWUIATdktABvOaBOgiAOziRKmfJEKUAFAEpDoAL7HTVlZAqglQhVtAB4mUHYAD0h2c204TR09AD5HDAEEUHN2AHdQF1AAXmTQJlcjU0rQSnZITEpzLNzQdLgXAG4vE09PRVV1AFU4dkoI6Nj4xN19CtNzFWJ2ItAAIhVsfBW5TyVa0Exh0cLQIZHcQOCO0BAAvYORzNPKRUJLQl3zwmRHe8pcecWuHsAxgHEoAGE1OwXK4bisAIIAIXBWz6agS4NedF+YxicQSWmmhi6ZleVhsdgcjhgOCU-gB7Ey5NQ5mQ5RJlSEYI6JJ6cl2kFJ5mxh2WmOFv0+l2c7WuYBG1EoAEI5DdWBxQABybJ5RwMpnWFlsoolcUikaa0ACLKEQXo1DIebYXYtQgtNhLbXNArFUBm36ahQWWgfQLfCzmv4MoGEEFgyHDGFy0AAJQGADkmABJDQAUVAuZTKYA8imADRCyP-BZLa2YOLsOgs9jaIA)

Comment: Thank you
This is just working the way i need